# How do I preserve escaped character values when using XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I am using XSLT to remove unnecessary attributes from some nodes in a file. Nodes which should not be transformed use the following simple template:

```xml
<!-- Copy everything else over -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

However, I have found that some nodes are loosing escaped characters contained in their attribute values.

For example, this input:

```xml
<field value="Lei Complementar No. 116/2003, Art. 6, &#167; 2&#186;, I."/>
```

end up looking like this:

```xml
<field value="Lei Complementar No. 116/2003, Art. 6, § 2º, I."/>
```

How can I prevent this unwanted transformation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I. XSLT 1.0 solution**:

**Just add this attribute to `xsl:output`:**

```
encoding="us-ascii"
```

This causes any non-ascii character to be rendered with its character code.

However, you may still get different outputs, such as:

```
<field value="Lei Complementar No. 116/2003, Art. 6, &#167; 2&#186;, I."/>
```

and

```
<field value="Lei Complementar No. 116/2003, Art. 6, &#xA7; 2&#xBA;, I." />
```

And, of course, all of these three are just different represenatations of the same string of (unicode) characters.

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

This uses the `<xsl:character-map>` instruction and must always produce the same output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"
   indent="yes" use-character-maps="chmEscapes"/>

 <xsl:character-map name="chmEscapes">
  <xsl:output-character character="&#167;"
                        string="&amp;#167"/>
  <xsl:output-character character="&#186;"
                        string="&amp;#186"/>
 </xsl:character-map>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<field value="Lei Complementar No. 116/2003, Art. 6, &#167; 2&#186;, I."/>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<field value="Lei Complementar No. 116/2003, Art. 6, &#167 2&#186, I."/>
```